# CSV file parsing in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io

Wanted to check if there is any null value in column field in the csv file and also there shouldn't be null value after / in number column, if it is null the entire row should  not be written to output file.

```
name,number,gender,country  
iva  1/001  f       Antartica  
aaju 2/002  m       russia  
lax  3/     m       brazil  
ana  4/004  f       Thailand  
vis  5/005  m
```

for e.g. 3rd and 5th row should not be written to output file.

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filepathop)) {

    for (int i = 0; i < csv.Length; i++) {

        {
            if (i == 0) {
                file.WriteLine(header + "," + "num" + "," + "serial" + "," + "date");
            }
            else {
                var newline = new StringBuilder(); 
                string[] words = csv[i].Split(',');
                string[] no = words[1].Split('/');
                string number = no[0];
                string serial = no[1];

                newline.Append(number + "," + serial + "," + tokens[0]);

                file.WriteLine(csv[i] + "," + newline);

            }
        }

    }

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your input does not appear to be comma separated, it seems to be fixed column width, white-space separated?

Comment: actually it is a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for null columns with `string.IsNullOrEmpty(column)` or `column.Length == 0` like so:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serial) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
    file.WriteLine(csv[i] + "," + newline);
```

You might want to check and remove white space, too. Depends on your input.